# Crashlytics: Archive Distribution Error: -3

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Since the latest builds I'm always getting the following error message when trying to upload the build to Crashlytics.

**Archive Distribution Error: -3**

`Could not upload the distribution. The operation couldn't be completed. (HTTP error 422.)`

I've tried the following:

- restart Xcode and Fabric plugin
- rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac
- different internet connections (WiFi, mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

We had a temporary issue where distributions could not be uploaded. That issue has been resolved, so you should be all set now to distribute now.

For reference, the [Fabric status page](http://status.fabric.io/) and [incident](http://status.fabric.io/incidents/0jgd1nj994wl).

Comment: Hi Mike, uploading is working now. However beta testers now get the error message "Download problem detected :["

Comment: Can you share the device logs of a device that has the issue? To get them:1) Choose Window -> Devices from the Xcode menu2) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device3) To see crash logs, select the View Device Logs button under the Device Information section on the right hand panel4) To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel to show the device console, then click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file.

A common issue on this is a certificate or profile that has expired.